# Visual C++: Call stack on assert failure

Tags: visual-c++, assert, callstack

Is it possible to output the **call stack** when an `assert` fails in **Release** mode?

I can see the call stack inside Visual Studio when an `assert` fails in **Debug** mode. I have compiled **Release** mode with `NDEBUG` removed so that assertions are compiled. When this `assert` fails, the assert parameters are printed onto the console. It would be very helpful if I can somehow get an output of the **call stack** too.

Comment: The debug info (function names and such) would have to be compiled into the binaries for this to be possible. Is that what you're asking how to do?

Answer (score 2):

There are two functions that should help: [CaptureStackBackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204633(v=vs.85).aspx) and [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650(v=vs.85).aspx) (requires Dbghelp.dll, here's [an example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx)).

Anyhow, both of them return you only a list of *return addresses*, so have to resolve them into function names manually.  You can set VS to generate a MAP file with addresses of all functions in you executable. Here's [how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2(v=vs.80).aspx).

Also, don't forget that some functions may (and will) be inlined. So don't be surprised when instead of `A -> B -> C` you will see `A -> C` calls tack.